# Jquery dataTables reverse sort columns in Rails coffee spirit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I use jquery DataTables in my rails app and in my coffee spirit file `sent_messages.js.coffee`
 i have a datatables call like this;

```
jQuery ->
        $('#sent_table').dataTable()
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
```

However, i want to reverse the first column but this;

```
jQuery ->
        $('#sent_table').dataTable()
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
        "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']]
```

Doesn't seem to work.
How can i pull it off the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a bit of CoffeeScript confusion. This:

```
$('#sent_table').dataTable()
sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
"aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']]
```

doesn't supply any options to the `dataTable` call, it is this JavaScript:

```
$('#sent_table').dataTable();
return { sPaginationType: "full_numbers", "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']] }
```

A quick fix for your function call should sort things out:

```
# No () and indent the options
$('#sent_table').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']]
```

or like this:

```
$('#sent_table').dataTable(
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']]
)
```